# Object Required Error after upgrading to Office 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have following sub that copies a chart passed to into a PowerPoint slide.  It's used to build a PowerPoint deck from charts and data in an Excel spreadsheet.   This code worked just fine in Excel 2010.  I've just been upgraded to Office 2013 and now I'm getting an "Object Required" Error on the `sr.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse` line.

```
Sub Copy_Chart(PPRes As PowerPoint.Presentation, SlideNumber As Integer, Chart As ChartObject, Top As Single, Left As Single, Height As Single, Width As Single)

    Dim sr As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
    Chart.Activate
    ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set sr = PPRes.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.Paste
    sr.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

    sr.Top = Top
    sr.Left = Left
    sr.Height = Height
    sr.Width = Width

End Sub
```

Comment: If you step through does `sr` get set properly?

Comment: I would say no.  I can confirm that the object is getting pasted into the PowerPoint presentation.  So, I'm guessing that the `Paste()` operation must not be returning the Shape Range anymore....

Comment: The help for PowerPoint 2013 shows the [Paste method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff745532.aspx) as returning a ShapeRange object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `Past` method must be returning an array of ShapeRanges.  I'm not sure if this is how it's always been and Office 2010 was a little more forgiving or not.  So, to correct for this issue, when referencing `sr` I've had to do like `sr(sr.Count)`.  Working code below...

```
Sub Copy_Chart(PPRes As PowerPoint.Presentation, SlideNumber As Integer, Chart As ChartObject, Top As Single, Left As Single, Height As Single, Width As Single)

    Dim sr As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
    Chart.Activate
    ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set sr = PPRes.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.Paste
    sr(sr.Count).LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

    sr(sr.Count).Top = Top
    sr(sr.Count).Left = Left
    sr(sr.Count).Height = Height
    sr(sr.Count).Width = Width

End Sub
```